# url disturbs the layout in php

Tags: php, html, layout

### I have found a problem in .htacess file only but not the solution

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)?$ findjob4.php?skills=$1
RewriteRule ^test-(.*)?$ findjob4.php?skills=$1

URL 1 : www.example.com/test-software
URL 2 : www.example.com/test/software
```

When using `URL 2` , the page gets disturbed layouts and when i use `URL 1` it working good (not a single error).
can any one let me know, why and what is the problem

just added new query above

---

I have a error using .htacess and normal url writes

### .htacess

```
RewriteRule ^search-jobs/(.*)?$ findjob4.php?skills=$1
```

### findjob4.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['skills']) or !empty($_GET['skills'])) {
        $d_skills = $_GET['skills'];
        $d_skills = str_replace('-', ' ', $d_skills);
    } else {
        $d_skills = ""; 
    }   
    $d_location = "texas";
    $page = 1;
?>

<?php require('header.php'); ?>

<div id="container">
    <?php  do_job_search6($d_skills, $d_location, $page); ?>
</div>
<?php require('footer.php'); ?>
```

Now when i open the url with    `findjob4.php?skills=software` its perfectly showing layouts.

where as `search-jobs/software` then results are good, but the layout is distrubed mainly in the footer region.

And i when i use `Developer Tools` in `Chrome` with `Inspect Element` and under tab `console`
i see

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/example/search-jobs/software/images/loadingAnimation.gif"
```

and this error is continous flowing.. and contents of the footer are changed with empty content of main container..

### Javascript : jquery lib error

```
(anonymous function)
jQuery.Callbacks.fire
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith
jQuery.extend.ready
```

I haved a image for below reference.

### Image1

[image]

### Image2

[image]

and below is the `ROOT_URL` constant, what i used for path.

```
<?php
    define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
    define('ROOT_URL', substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, - (strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) - strlen(ROOT_DIR))));
?>
```

Comment: I believe you're suffering from a path problem. `/example/search-jobs/software/images/loadingAnimation.gif` should probably be `/example/images/loadingAnimation.gif`.

Comment: Checking the source code under the `Element` tab in Chrome does not show you the actual source. It shows you the version Chrome is rendering, with any errors "fixed". (i.e. missing end tags filled in)

Comment: @rodneyrehm, yes indeed what I suspected. `example/search-jobs/software/images/loadingAnimation.gif` are rewritten to be `findjob4.php?skills=/software/images/loadingAnimation.gif`

Comment: i am not using this `loadingAnimation.gif` image... i dont know where  it came from..

Comment: @rodneyrehm , i have found the problem but when i try with `.htacess` url 2 its not working..

Answer (score -2):

Use the absolute path to the image instead of the relative path.

```
<img src="http://localhost/example/images/loadingAnimation.gif" />
```

as opposed to

```
<img src="images/loadingAnimation.gif" />
```

Comment: Of course not hardcoded into the HTML, lol. I mean the output of the PHP should show the absolute path. `<img src="<?php echo SITE_DIR; ?>images/loadingAnimation.gif" />`

Comment: [*facepalm*](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_uSt19t4qIuM/TTqXHNwYHnI/AAAAAAAAAgU/WzTTb-KuEV4/s1600/facepalm.jpg)

Comment: I am not worried about `loadingAnimation.gif` image. I trying to get the layout properly.. all css and scripts are working good, but problem with layout, in footer, it shows whole page content.. two times.

Comment: @AdnanShammout what do you suggest?